# customize Grape API response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am using  Grape GEM in my rails app, How can I customize  response
if record not found or request params are in valid

@video = Video.where(id: permitted_params[:id]).first!

for example there is no record for any id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
@video = Video.where(id: permitted_params[:id]).first!
if @video
   #your code
else
  error!({:error_message => "Record Could not found"}, 422)
end
```